# Error reading the character of a string

Tags: c++

```
#include <algorithm>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include "kcftracker.hpp"

#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if (argc > 5) return -1;

    bool HOG = true;
    bool FIXEDWINDOW = false;
    bool MULTISCALE = true;
    bool SILENT = true;
    bool LAB = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        if ( strcmp (argv[i], "hog") == 0 )
            HOG = true;
        if ( strcmp (argv[i], "fixed_window") == 0 )
            FIXEDWINDOW = true;
        if ( strcmp (argv[i], "singlescale") == 0 )
            MULTISCALE = false;
        if ( strcmp (argv[i], "show") == 0 )
            SILENT = false;
        if ( strcmp (argv[i], "lab") == 0 ){
            LAB = true;
            HOG = true;
        }
        if ( strcmp (argv[i], "gray") == 0 )
            HOG = false;
    }

    // Create KCFTracker object
    KCFTracker tracker(HOG, FIXEDWINDOW, MULTISCALE, LAB);

    // Frame readed
    Mat frame;

    // Tracker results
    Rect result;

    // Path to list.txt
    ifstream listFile;
    string fileName = "C:\\Users\PeterLin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project7\x64\Debug\ball\images.txt";
    listFile.open(fileName);
```

Every time I run this code, the system tell me that there's error in reading the string and cannot get the filename. I wonder the reason.

Comment: You should escape \ properly. `\P` is not a valid escape. I bet you received a warning about it.

Comment: You seemed to know that, since you doubled the first backslash. Why didn't you double all the rest for the same reason?

Comment: You can also use forward slash instead. Windows has allowed either type of slash in filenames for a very long time.

Comment: I have tried to change the code to    string fileName = "C:/Users/PeterLin/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Project7/x64/Debug/ball/images.txt"; but the same problem exists. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the \ properly.

If escaping them is too much of a pain, which they usually can be you can try using a verbatim string literal. 
Used as a prefix it asks the compiler to ignore escape characters. Very useful when writing regex.

Have a read here :
http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings

Comment: I have tried to change the code to    string fileName = "C:/Users/PeterLin/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Project7/x64/Debug/ball/images.txt"; but the same problem exists. Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that some other program is accessing the file ? (A text editor etc). I really don't think it's a permission issue, and I do assume you have the path right.